# How to update a Lookup field and a user field in SharePoint with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a way how to update a lookup field and a user field with Microsoft graph ?
I can read the item, but I don't find a way to create or update this kind of field even if I put a correct ID value.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it is supported to update lookup fields via Microsoft Graph API.

Lets say there is a field named `Category`, then depending whether lookup field is represented as single or multi valued, the following examples demonstrate how to set lookup field value.

for *single-valued* field:

```
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields    
Method: PATCH 
Body: {
  "CategoryLookupId": "1"
}
```

where

- `field name` is provided in the following format: `{field-name}LookupId`
- `field value` corresponds to lookup id and provided as a string

for *multi-valued* field

```
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields    
Method: PATCH 
{
    "CategoryLookupId@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
    "CategoryLookupId":["1","2"]
}
```

Comment: How to we get the lookupid from the email of the user who is part of sharepoint site?