# MS GRAPH FieldValueSet for Updating a Person Field with graph .NET API

Tags: sharepoint, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I tried to update a Person filed named "CurrentAssignedTo"
like so:

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet                {
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
    {"CurrentQueue", "Editor"},{"JobStatus", $"Questions answered by {comm.User}"}, 
    {"CurrentAssignedToId", comm.Editor.Id.ToString()}        }                };
```

But the line:

```
await graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[list.Id].Items[items[0].Id].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);
```

Errors on the name "CurrentAssignedToId" (Like I used to do with SharePoint API)

But if I use "CurrentAssignedTo" it does not update the person field.

Anyone knows how to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701107/how-do-i-update-the-value-of-person-or-group-columns-in-sharepoint-lists-using-t/59448206#59448206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Graph API, should append LookupId after person field name like below:

Update: the person field value should be int value not string value.

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

```
    var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"Title", "Title123"},
            {"CurrentAssignedToLookupId", 15}
        }
    };

    var result = graphClient.Sites["siteId"].Lists["ListId"].Items["ItemId"].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);
```

[image]

Comment: In my code , comm.Editor.Id.ToString() =="6" and still no work

Comment: @OferGal, the issue is less related with the value, you are using the wrong property name change CurrentAssignedToId to CurrentAssignedToLookupId

Comment: Updated the post, change value to int type rather than string type.

Comment: So what was for SharePoint API  ***Id  is now ***LookupId in Graph? Does MSFT want to make everything difficult on purpose? :-)

Comment: @OferGal, this is actually CurrentAssignedToLookupId in Graph API, you can do a GET request in Graph Explorer with this endpoint:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/Lists/ListId/items/itemid

Does MSFT want to make everything difficult on purpose? :-)  No, this is some difference in Graph API :-)

Comment: @OferGal, please try the suggestion in the post,if you updates, please share the info. :)

Comment: Yes The {personField}LookupId works fine! Thank you  @jerry_MSFT

Comment: Hi Ofer, Glad to hear it's working now. You could accept this reply as answer so that it will be useful to other in the forum who have similiar question. Best Regard :)

Comment: I can see how to flag it as bad But ignorant me, I do not see how to flag it as a good answer. (new question :-) )  Got it Forget me :-)

Comment: You can edit some words in original question and then I will upvote the question for you :)